# How to obtain full width in PivotItem

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, pivotviewer

In XAML, PivotItems don't have full width of the screen on a Windows Phone. This is good behavior and design, but for a single image I want it to fill the entire screenwidth.

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: have you tried by playing with margins?

Comment: Yes, afaik I've set everything to margin="0", from Pivot to Grid, everything.

Comment: Post some piece of xaml code, it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The root cause is that default `PivotItemMargin` is set to `12,0,12,0`. We can find the setting in generic.xaml.

So what we need to do is overridding the setting in App.xaml. Just like this:
`<Thickness x:Key="PivotItemMargin">0</Thickness>`

Comment: This is the real answer. Negative margins are the wrong way to go.

Comment: This answer was added quite a bit later, but I totally agree! Marked as answer!

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution, having a negative margin

```
<controls:Pivot>
    <controls:PivotItem Margin="-10,0,-10,0">
        <Grid />
    </controls:PivotItem>

    <controls:PivotItem Margin="-10,0,-10,0">
        <Grid />
    </controls:PivotItem>
</controls:Pivot>
```

Of course you can also use a regular pivot and only have the image margin set to -10,0,-10,0

Comment: See below for overriding the template. Negative margins are a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this code,

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="NikhilSApp.DemoExample"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"     
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="800"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <!--Pivot Control-->

    // You can specify the width here....
    <controls:Pivot Height="800" Width="480">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem Height="800" Margin="0,-130,0,0">
            <Grid Name="GridMediaQuestion">
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/Guess.png" Margin="10,10,10,10" Name="imgReceived" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="790" Width="470" />
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <controls:PivotItem Height="800" >
            <Grid x:Name="GridPivot2" Background="#ffffc0">
                 // Place Your Second pivot's  Content here
             </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

It is Working..
I implemented already... :)

Comment: You can also specify the width to particular one Pivot Item only.

Comment: But according to this page, there are multiple resolutions available. Setting it to 480 width doesn't give full width on every device?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: then You can set it from back end like 

Pivot1.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

Pivot1.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment .Stretch;

Comment: Setting the width doesn't help, because there are margins coming from somewhere. I've tried setting the width to 1000 but it still has a margin on the left. Perhaps WPF or RT works differently, but in Windows Phone it didn't work.